# File with build action "None" not ignored by ReSharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have a `.config` file in my solution, but it is not the actual Visual Studio `.config` file. It is only a file that has to be copied to the output folder.

I have set the build action in the properties window to `None`, but the file is still being analyzed by ReSharper.

I have found a way to ignore the file in the "Errors in Solution" window, but that is not a setting that I can commit to svn. So it is only a personal setting.

How can I make sure that files that are set to `None` are ignored by ReSharper?

[image]

This is the file and it is certainly not of the .config format that visual studio wants:

```
ID=ID
Waterbody=Waterbody
Watertype=Watertype
Weirs=Weirs
Meandering=Meandering
Shading=Shading
Banks=Banks
LevelControl=LevelControl
Maintenance=Maintenance
Shipping=Shipping
Connectivity=Connectivity
P-total=P-total
N-total=N-total
BOD=BOD
Chloride=Chloride
EQRfytoplankton=EQRfytoplankton
EQRaquaflora=EQRaquaflora
EQRmacroinv=EQRmacroinv
EQRfish=EQRfish
```

Answer (score 0):

You may [share ReSharper settings accross team](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html#d250059e11616) to make sure this file is ignored anywhere:

> The corresponding settings file .sln.DotSettings is
>   saved in the solution folder.  As soon as this file is added to your
>   VCS and the team members get it, ReSharper applies these settings
>   automatically without reloading the solution.

Helpful discussion:
[How to share the same Resharper settings between multiple solutions, with no manual intervention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896096/how-to-share-the-same-resharper-settings-between-multiple-solutions-with-no-man)

Also, another option to ignore file is (in R# 9.2):

> Resharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Settings -> Elements To Skip

And R# file ignoring is independant from Build Action.

Hope it helps!

Comment: These are good workarounds, but I would like to tell ReSharper to ignore the config files that are set to None.